# Texto de input fica atras de icone

Tags: react-native

Eu tenho um projeto em reactNative que tem um Input no topo e a direita desse input tenho um ícone de lupa mas ao escrever quando chego a esse icone, o texto fica atras do icone, como eu faço para quando o texto chegar a uns 10px de distancia do icone ele começar a empurrar o texto para trás?

[image: Problema]

Codigo

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, TextInput, StyleSheet, Image, Text, FlatList } from 'react-native';
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-native-fontawesome';
import { faSearch } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';
export default function Region(){
return(
    <View style={style.mainBox}>
        <View style={style.searchBox}>
            <TextInput style={style.searchInput} placeholder="Pesquise um estabelecimento" />
            <FontAwesomeIcon size={22} style={style.searchImg} icon={ faSearch } />
        </View>
    </View>
 );
}

const style = StyleSheet.create({
mainBox:{
    flex: 1,
},
searchImg: {
    marginTop: 18,
    position: 'absolute',
    right: 16,
    color: '#ccc',
},
searchBox: {
    alignContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
},
searchInput: {
    backgroundColor: '#FFF',
    width: '97%',
    borderColor: '#CCC',
    borderWidth: 1,
    marginTop: 5,
    borderRadius: 5,
    padding: 10
}
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basta adicionar um `paddingRight`:

```
searchInput: {
    backgroundColor: '#FFF',
    width: '97%',
    borderColor: '#CCC',
    borderWidth: 1,
    marginTop: 5,
    borderRadius: 5,
    padding: 10,
    paddingRight: 50,
}
```

Se "50" ainda não der, vai adicionando mais conforme a necessidade.